# Unable to install nodejs script from nodesource

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, nodejs

I am using this command that suppose to install Nodejs Script from node source

```
sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
```

But it always return

```
Err:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chromre/deb table/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chromre/deb table/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/chromre/deb table/main Translation-en_US
Ign:13 http://dl.google.com/linux/chromre/deb table/main Translation-en
Ign:14 http://dl.google.com/linux/chromre/deb table/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 http://dl.google.com/linux/chromre/deb table/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chromre/deb table Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chromre/deb/dists/table/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I already had tried to run setup_6.x from my local PC . But still return same result. And i also had replaced `deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chromre/deb/ table main` that with `deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chromre/deb/ table main` at source.list
But it doesn't worked out for me till now. 
So please help me to solve it , i am newbie at ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend installing the latest version of Node.js natively as a snap package rather than trying to install the Node.js package from nodesource.com.

Node.js is available as a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. Specific to Node.js, developers can choose from one or more of the currently supported releases and get regular automatic updates directly from NodeSource. Node.js versions 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 and 18 are currently available, with the Snap Store being updated within hours or minutes of a Node.js release.

Node can be installed with a single command, for example:

```
sudo snap install node --classic --channel 11/stable
```

The node snap can be accessed by the command `node`, for example:

```
$ node -v  
v11.5.0
```

An up-to-date version of npm will installed as part of the node snap. npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell. After installing the node snap run the following command to enable npm update checking:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/your-username/.config
```

Replace  **`your-username`** in the above command with your own username. Then run `npm -v` to check if the version of npm is up-to-date. As an example I checked that npm was up-to-date, checked the version of an already installed package named yarn with the command `npm list yarn` and then updated the existing yarn package to the latest version with the command `npm update yarn`

Users can switch between versions of Node.js at any time without needing to involve additional tools like nvm (Node Version Manager), for example:

```
sudo snap refresh node --channel=10/stable
```

Users can test bleeding-edge versions of Node.js that can be installed from the latest edge channel by switching with:

```
sudo snap switch node --edge
```

This approach is only recommended for those users who are willing to participate in testing and bug reporting upstream.

#### Node.js LTS schedule

| Release | Status | Codename | Initial release | LTS Start | Maintenance Start | Maintenance End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6.x | EOL | Boron | 2016-04-26 | 2016-10-18 | 2018-04-30 | 2019-04-30 |
| 7.x | EOL |  | 2017-05-30 |  |  | 2017-06-30 |
| 8.x | EOL | Carbon | 2016-10-25 | 2017-10-31 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-12-31 |
| 9.x | EOL |  | 2017-10-01 |  |  | 2018-06-30 |
| 10.x | EOL | Dubnium | 2018-04-24 | 2018-10-30 | 2020-05-19 | 2021-04-30 |
| 11.x | EOL |  | 2018-10-23 |  |  | 2019-06-01 |
| 12.x | Maintenance LTS | Erbium | 2019-04-23 | 2019-10-21 | 2020-11-301 | 2022-04-30 |
| 13.x | EOL |  | 2019-10-22 |  |  | 2020-06-01 |
| 14.x | Maintenance LTS | Fermium | 2020-04-21 | 2020-10-27 | 2021-10-30 | 2023-04-30 |
| 16.x | Active LTS | Gallium | 2021-04-20 | 2021-10-26 | 2022-10-18 | 2024-04-30 |
| 17.x | Current |  | 2021-10-19 |  | 2022-04-01 | 2022-06-01 |
| 18.x | Current |  | 2022-04-19 | 2022-10-25 | 2023-10-18 | 2025-04-30 |