# Different versions of Node and NodeJS on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nodejs

I've just installed nodejs on my system using`sudo apt-get install nodejs` and `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`. after that I've installed nvm and updated nodejs to the latest LTS version. but If I check `node -v` it says `v8.11.1` and If I type `nodejs -v` it shows `v4.2.6`. how to solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install nodejs script from nodesource](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019944/unable-to-install-nodejs-script-from-nodesource)

Comment: this is not duplicate question. I've already tried that but it's not working for me.

Comment: @Samuel It would help if you could write what exactly you tried to solve the problem and how it failed.

Comment: please check above question as I already mention that it's showing different versions.

Comment: Any particular reason you expect them to be the same? What's the output of `which node` and the output of `which node-js` ? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742961/node-vs-nodejs-version